# Can't create file into specific folder using gspread google colab

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory, gspread

Yesterday I was still able to create a google sheet files using gspread into a specific folder using this code:

`ss = gc.create(fileName,"my folder destination")`

But today, this code yields an error.

Here is my full code:

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

import pandas as pd

import gspread
from google.auth import default
creds, _ = default()

gc = gspread.authorize(creds)

wb = gc.open('file name')
ws = wb.worksheet('sheet name')

# get_all_values gives a list of rows.
rows = ws.get_all_values()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows[1:],columns=rows[0])

modisseries = df["column name"]
uniquemodis = modisseries.drop_duplicates().tolist()

def createSpreadsheet(columName):
  ndf = df[df["Modis"] == Columname]
  nlist = [ndf.columns.tolist()] + ndf.to_numpy().tolist()
  ss = gc.create(columnName,"Folder_id")
  nws = ss.sheet1
  nws.update_title(columnName)
  nws.update("A1",nlist,value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")

for modis in uniquemodis:
  createSpreadsheet(modis)
```

And here is the error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5c297289782b> in <module>()
     30 
     31 for column_value in uniquecolumn:
---> 32   createSpreadsheet(column_value)

<ipython-input-1-5c297289782b> in createSpreadsheet(column_value)
     24   nlist = [ndf.columns.tolist()] + ndf.to_numpy().tolist()
     25 
---> 26   ss = gc.create(column_value,"folder_id")
     27   nws = ss.sheet1
     28   nws.update_title(column_value)

TypeError: create() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: Please considere to add the error message you are getting.

Comment: hi @AlessandroTogni, thank you for your concern. i already add the error message. could you give me some solutions?

Comment: Where is the call to the `createSpreadsheet` function that generates the error?
How is `column_value` defined?

Comment: hi @AlessandroTogni if i print the loop

sorry, I think i miss to paste when I share the full code, I already update it

```for column_value in uniquecolumn:
 print(column_value)```

it will return the
df["column name"]

yesterday the same code is working without any changing

Comment: Maybe the data you input are different from the ones for yesterday?

Comment: there are no updated data @AlessandroTogni
i just re run the scrip

Answer (score 0):

Hi which version of `gspread` do you use ?
The parameter `folder_id` has been introduced in version 3.5.0

From the error message you get it seems you have an old version and it does not handle the *new* parameter `folder_id`.

You can check the version you are currently using by using: `print(gspread.__version__)`

If this is bellow version 3.5.0 then run the following command:
`python3 -m pip install -U gspread`